# Copying and pasting texts from external sites into pythonanywhere.com

Tags: flask, pythonanywhere

I have a pythonanywhere.com account and I have been trying to copy and paste from external sites such as pastebin.com into pythonanywhere.com. Does anybody know why this is?

Comment: What is the issue that you're encountering?

Comment: So I have a Pythonanywhere.com account and I am trying to URL link to a webpage but its broken somehow. I have tried everything it doesn't work.

Comment: That sounds more like an issue that you should bring up with pythonanywhere.com support.